# how to disable dropdown option, if the data from another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to disable one of my dropdown option and make it look like placeholder. I know how to make disable if the option we write on the same component, but how do we make it if the dropdown data from another component.
what I want to do is the label `Choose One` will be the placeholder and cant be selected. and if I want to create it on same component I just can write `<option selected disabled>Choose One</option>` but I don't know how to create it if the dropdown data from another components
. Any Help will be appreciate. Thank you in advance!

**Constant.js**

```
export const dropdownDenied= [
  {
    label: "Choose one",
    value: ""
  },
  {
    label: "None",
    value: "0"
  },
  {
    label: "Retail",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    label: "Customer",
    value: "2"
  },
]
```

**App.js**

```
class ContentReceived extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    dropSelected : ""
     }

handleSelected = dropSelected => {
    this.setState({dropSelected})
  }

render(){

const { dropSelected } = this.props

return(
        //First DropDown

       <Select
        disabled={false}
        onChange={this.handleSelected}
        value={dropSelected}
      >
        {dropdownDenied.map((item, index) => (
         <option value={item.value || ""} key={index}>
         {item.label}  
         </option>
         ))}
      </Select>
```

Comment: at which options do you need to disable them ? Do you need to disable it for all the elements in `dropdownDenied` array ?

Comment: Can you define better the disable operation? Right now `disabled={false}` is always false, so question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @KavinduVIndika @axel I'm sorry for unclear question, what I want to do is the label `Choose One`  will be the placeholder and cant be selected. and if I want to create it on same component I just can write `<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose One</option>` but I don't know how to create it if the dropdown data from another components

Answer (score 0):

how if add disable in the constant.js, so its look like

```
export const dropdownDenied= [
  {
    label: "Choose one",
    value: "",
    disable: true
  },
 ...
  ]
```

Comment: thank you for the comment, and it's not working, but even its working I can't do it right on the constant component, because I just need to disable on specific dropdown. not all dropdown.

Comment: its work well for me, you just need add disable: true on item that you want set it disable, and set false for item that you want it can choose,

Comment: `<option selected="true" disabled={item.disable}>Choose One</option>`